# Checking for user permissions with Spatie package fails in routes and in controller

Tags: laravel

I tried to use **spatie/laravel-permission** (https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/installation-laravel) to set up permissions and **Laravel Breeze** to create a login functionality (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits)

This is a database seeder which creates 2 users and sets permissions/roles

```
public function run()
{

    app()[\Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar::class]->forgetCachedPermissions();

    Permission::create(['name' => 'manage posts']);

    // Create user with "premium" role
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => 'regular user',
        'email' => 'user@domain.com',
        'password' => Hash::make('123123'),
    ]);
    $premium = Role::create(['name' => 'premium'])
        ->givePermissionTo(['manage posts']);
    $user->assignRole($premium);

    // Create super admin
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => 'superadmin user',
        'email' => 'admin@domain.com',
        'password' => Hash::make('123123'),
    ]);
    $super_admin = Role::create(['name' => 'super-admin']);
    $user->assignRole($super_admin);
}
```

This is how I'm testing it inside a controller, something seems off but I think I do it correctly (https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/role-permissions)

```
// Both of these is giving me false for some reason when I'm logged in for both users
$user = Auth::user();
// $user->assignRole('super-admin'); // this also doesn't change anything
var_dump('has role super-admin', $user->hasRole('super-admin')); 
var_dump('can manage posts', $user->can('manage posts'));

// But both of these queries correctly fetches usernames which correspond to seeded data, so that part should be ok
$users = User::permission('manage posts')->get();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    var_dump($user->name);
}
$users = User::role('super-admin')->get();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    var_dump($user->name);
}
```

Routes also doesn't work, I get a message "User does not have the right roles" when I'm logged in as super-admin

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:super-admin']], function () {
    Route::resource('posts', \App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class)->middleware(['auth']);
});
```

Model for User

```
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    use HasRoles;
    ... 
}
```

Laravel and Spatie package are latest version. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step by step
every time you run command check the table in database and be sure what the data inserted you got it ?

**first we insert permission i prefer to write the premission in this way as example**  "read_tags"
in your example

```
Permission::create(['name' => 'manage_posts']);
```

**then**
create role

```
$role = Role::firstOrCreate(['name' => 'super-admin']);
```

and make sync permissions to role
$role->syncPermissions(Permission::all());
**call the first user or whatever u create the user here**

```
$user = User::first();
```

**then give the user this role**

> ```
>     $user->syncRoles($role);
> ```

try to make it as following
and don't forget to show the database and be sure the tables have the data